# IIS 7: ASPX site returns 404 (no handler) or 500 (with handler)

Tags: iis, asp.net, iis-7, http-status-code-404, asp

I have a site that ran well for about 8 years on Server 2003/IIS 6. I recently migrated to Server 2008/IIS 7, and the site is no longer running (???). The site is located on `E:\`, so nothing was changed when the OS was refreshed.

I recreated the site after the OS install (just like I would for IIS6). When I navigate to `default.aspx` from another machine, I get a 404 error:

[image: IIS7 Page Not Found 404 Error]

I'm not sure why I get the error since the page is there. And more bizarre is the favorite icon is served but not the page.

I've been poking around in the dark trying to find a solution. Some Googling took to me to missing Handler Maps, and there was nothing for ASP or ASPX at the server level or the site level. So I added a top level handler for the server according to [Add a Managed Handler Mapping (IIS 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753249%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)):

```
Name: ASP and ASPX Default Handler
Request Path: *.asp, *,aspx
Type: System.Web.Handlers
```

I verified the above handler was enabled at the site level. But the above did not work as I got a different 404 error (if there is such a thing):

[image: IIS7 Page Not Found 404 Error]

I also tried changing permissions on the handler to add script and execute. That did not work either. I even deleted the Application Pool and recreated it. That did not work either. And adding `aspnet_isapi.dll` as the type caused a 500 server error (per another page's suggestion).

EDIT (OCT-12-2013): I uninstalled and reinstalled Web Server IIS 7 (the server role). This time, I followed the instructions at [How to Install IIS 7 and Setup a Static Website in 13 Easy Steps](http://www.trainsignal.com/blog/windows-server-2008-iis7).  No joy (and I could not find a useful Microsoft page on installing IIS 7. For example, this is the junk they are trying to claim is documentation: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725762.aspx).

Any ideas what Microsoft has done to break a simple ASPX site? Or any ideas what hoops I should try to jump through next?

Comment: Do you have Authenticated Users specified in the permissions for the website folder?

Comment: Yes, I looked at permission. `<Machine>\Users` is on the folder (and there are no unknown SIDs).

Comment: But is the Authenticated Users group there?

Comment: Thanks Yassar. This is a stand alone server in the DMZ. There is no `Authenticated Users` group.

Comment: Thanks again Yassar. I was able to work around it by installing the Application Development tools on the server. Its sickening to me to setup a development machine on a production box in a DMZ, so I am planning an Apache migration now.